# Trying to migrate user data into multi value term reference field

Tags: 7, migrations, taxonomy-terms

FYI: I'm using the module Migrate 7.x-2.5

I'm trying to migrate users from a custom built PHP website, backed by a mysql database, into Drupal.

Each user can have multiple statutes assigned to him. In the source database I have a table 'users' with a column 'stat_id'.

```
+---------+---------+
| user_id | stat_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 | ;2;     |
|       2 | ;26;    |
|       3 | ;3;     |
|       4 | ;27;28; |
|       5 | ;19;2;  |
+---------+---------+
```

The name of the statutes is stored in the table 'users_statuut'.

```
+---------+----------------------------+
| stat_id | statuut_nl                 |
+---------+----------------------------+
|       1 | Doctoraatsstudent          |
|       2 | Postdoctoraal onderzoeker  |
|       3 | Administratieve medewerker |
|       6 | Diensthoofd                |
|       7 | Laborant                   |
+---------+----------------------------+
```

In Drupal I created a term vocabulary 'statutes' with the names of all the statutes.
And I added a term reference field to the user profile that can select multiple values from this vocabulary.

What I can't figure out is how to migrate the data from the source table into Drupal.
I've already managed to migrate simple fields like username, email, password,... so that's working, but I have no idea how to get the statutes into the term reference field.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [callback](https://drupal.org/node/1133448#callbacks) with a separator to transform the source value to the destination value. For example:

```
  $this->addFieldMapping('statuut_nl', 'stat_id')
   ->separator(';')
   ->callbacks(array($this, 'computeValue'));

  protected function computeValue($value) {
    $allowed_values = array(
      2 => 'Postdoctoraal onderzoeker',
      ...
    );

    return ($allowed_values[$value]);
  }
```